# Unhandeled exception Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting unhandled exception in my code and my app is not working.

This is the only one error which I can find in the logs:

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

E/flutter (30126): #0 AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails (package:driverapp/Assistant/assistantMethods.dart:63:41)

E/flutter (30126): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (30126): #1 _NewRideScreenState.getPlaceDirection (package:driverapp/AllScreens/newRideScreen.dart:189:19)

E/flutter (30126): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (30126): #2 _NewRideScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:driverapp/AllScreens/newRideScreen.dart:70:15)

E/flutter (30126): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (30126):
```

This is my `assistantMethod.dart` file code:

```
static Future<DirectionDetails> obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(LatLng initialPosition, LatLng finalPosition)async

{

String directionUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${initialPosition.latitude},${initialPosition.longitude}&destination=${finalPosition.latitude},${finalPosition.longitude}&key=$mapKey";

var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(directionUrl);

if(res == "failed")

{

return null;

}

DirectionDetails directionDetails = DirectionDetails();
```

#1 error points out at this line

```
directionDetails.encodedPoints = res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];

directionDetails.distanceText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"];

directionDetails.distanceValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];

directionDetails.durationText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"];

directionDetails.durationValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"];

return directionDetails;

}
```

#2 error points out this line

```
var details = await AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(pickUpLatLng, dropOffLatLng);
```

#3 error points out this line

```
await getPlaceDirection(currentLatLng, pickUpLatLng);
```

Please help me do this right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be causing your error:

`directionDetails.encodedPoints = res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];`.

Please post the `res` json to take a look at it.I think there would be an `index` before `points`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a List and your putting a KEY instead of a int (index) on the list, check your api response.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it works. My steps

#### 0) Fetch JSON in browser

To fetch data we are using URL (with points from Google examples):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json
?origin=Disneyland
&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood
&key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>
```

The response has such structure:
[image]

#### 1) Fetch response as `String`

I use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library.

```
Future<String> fetchData() async {
  String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
      "?origin=Disneyland"
      "&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood"
      "&key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>";

  var client = http.Client();
  var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url));

  String body = response.body;

  return body;
}
```

#### 2) Parse received data

Received data are just `String`. Base on documentation we know that's JSON format. So let's decode that:

```
String body = await fetchData();
var res = json.decode(body);
```

#### 3) Find necessary fields

When you have JSON you can iterate it and get necessary data, for example:

```
var distanceText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"];
var distanceValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];
var durationText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"];
var durationValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"];
var encodedPoints = res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];
```

and it works :)

## My idea how to make it better

#### 1) Fetch JSON in Flutter

I use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library.

Fetch data and return response as String:

```
Future<String> fetchData() async {
  String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
      "?origin=Disneyland"
      "&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood"
      "&key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>";

  var response = await Requests.get(url);

  String body = response.content();

  return body;
}
```

#### 2) Convert received data in to models (classes)

The easiest way is to use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) which:

> produces nice types and JSON (de)serializers for many programming languages. It can infer types from JSON but also takes types from JSON Schema, TypeScript, and GraphQL.

what you have to do is to:

> paste JSON on the left, and code appears on the right.

So you will receive classes, for example:

```
class DirectionDetails {
  DirectionDetails({
    this.geocodedWaypoints,
    this.routes,
    this.status,
  });

  final List<GeocodedWaypoint> geocodedWaypoints;
  final List<Route> routes;
  final String status;

  factory DirectionDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DirectionDetails(
        geocodedWaypoints: json["geocoded_waypoints"] == null
            ? null
            : List<GeocodedWaypoint>.from(json["geocoded_waypoints"].map((x) => GeocodedWaypoint.fromJson(x))),
        routes: json["routes"] == null ? null : List<Route>.from(json["routes"].map((x) => Route.fromJson(x))),
        status: json["status"] == null ? null : json["status"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "geocoded_waypoints":
            geocodedWaypoints == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(geocodedWaypoints.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "routes": routes == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(routes.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "status": status == null ? null : status,
      };
}
```

You will also receive methods allowing you to convert directly to and from json string:

```
DirectionDetails directionDetailsFromJson(String str) => DirectionDetails.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String directionDetailsToJson(DirectionDetails data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
```

So in your case you have to use `directionDetailsFromJson` to receive Flutter data structure.

#### 3) Find necessary fields

When you have whole data structure you can find all of the data which you need, so:

```
List<Widget> parseData(DirectionDetails directionDetails) {
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  return directionDetails.routes.map((route) {
    var points = route.overviewPolyline.points;

    List<PointLatLng> decodedPoints = polylinePoints.decodePolyline(points);

    var distanceText = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.distance.text).join();
    var distanceValue = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.distance.value).join();

    var durationText = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.duration.text).join();
    var durationValue = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.duration.value).join();

    var stringPoints =  decodedPoints.join("\n");

    return Text(
      "distanceText: $distanceText\n\n"
      "distanceValue: $distanceValue\n\n"
      "durationText: $durationText\n\n"
      "durationValue: $durationValue\n\n"
      "points:\n$stringPoints",
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

To decode PolylinePoints I use [flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points) library.

#### 4) Result

[image]

#### 5) Whole code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> items = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Fetch Data"),
              onPressed: download,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => items[index],
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                itemCount: items.length,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void download() async {
    String body = await fetchData();
    DirectionDetails directionDetails = directionDetailsFromJson(body);
    var routes = parseData(directionDetails);

    setState(() {
      items = routes;
    });
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
        "?origin=Disneyland"
        "&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood"
        "&key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>";

    var client = http.Client();
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url));

    String body = response.body;

    return body;
  }

  List<Widget> parseData(DirectionDetails directionDetails) {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    return directionDetails.routes.map((route) {
      var points = route.overviewPolyline.points;

      List<PointLatLng> decodedPoints = polylinePoints.decodePolyline(points);

      var distanceText = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.distance.text).join();
      var distanceValue = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.distance.value).join();

      var durationText = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.duration.text).join();
      var durationValue = route.legs.map((leg) => leg.duration.value).join();

      var stringPoints = decodedPoints.join("\n");

      return Text(
        "distanceText: $distanceText\n\n"
        "distanceValue: $distanceValue\n\n"
        "durationText: $durationText\n\n"
        "durationValue: $durationValue\n\n"
        "points:\n$stringPoints",
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```